# JQuery Themeroller css Wrapping Accordion header

Tags: jquery, css, themeroller

I am using a JQuery Themeroller theme from Jquery UI 1.8.10.  I want to change my theme using themeroller.  The current themeroller version is for jquery UI 1.9.  When I download the a new theme and implement the CSS/images, the headers on my accordion menu's are doubling in size.  The Arrow icon is on one line and the header text is wrapped down to the next line.

Is there a way to access the previous version of jquery UI Themeroller?  Or alternatively, is there a small fix to this that others have found?  My biggest worry is that I miss one css line somewhere that doesn't get caught by a regression test.

Comment: As a workaround for now I was able to get the header issue itself resolved by replacing the .ui-accordion css lines with the old version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Accessing Legacy versions of JQueryUI and Themeroller**

You can rebuild the quick access links at the bottom of their site to use the version you are looking for.

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.10/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.js

You can see the release history on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI#Release_history) to see which version of JQuery pairs up with the release.

You can access prebuild supported themeroller themes for legacy versions [here](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/02/jquery-ui-download-builderthemeroller-status/)

*[Google CDN Links for legacy JQueryUI](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery-ui)*

**In regards to the custom JQueryUI and Themeroller package builder.**

That is currently not supported for legacy versions.  They are working towards a solution, but none currently exist. [Reference](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/02/jquery-ui-download-builderthemeroller-status/)

Comment: What do you mean when you say rebuild the links?  Are you referring to the Quick Access links?

Comment: @Joseph Yes sorry I will clarify in my answer

Comment: This gets me the base .css file, but doesn't let me use the themeroller webpage to custom create a theme then export it as a 1.8 css file.

Comment: @Joseph That is a known issue and they are working on solutions, but currently you cannot build custom JQueryUI or Themeroller packages for legacy versions. [Source](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/02/jquery-ui-download-builderthemeroller-status/)

Comment: Ok, just wanted to make sure before chasing down too many rabbit holes.  I'll either do a find/replace on the color codes (only thing I care about) or export the 1.9 and replace the applicable accordion pieces.